# Qt4 QMenu items sorting

Tags: qt, qt4

I am using QT4 and dynamically adding entries to a QMenu.  Is it possible to sort the entries in the QMenu without deleting it and creating a new one?

I originally thought there was a function to insert at a specific location so I could sort on insert, but I have not been able to locate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once added, I don't think you can reorder. While you are creating though you could use the [QWidget::insertAction](http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/qwidget.html#insertAction) method to place it exactly where you want it.

```
void QWidget::insertAction ( QAction * before, QAction * action )
```

Otherwise you could use [QWidget::addActions](http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/qwidget.html#addActions). Create your list of Actions and sort it before adding to the QMenu.

```
void QWidget::addActions ( QList<QAction *> actions )
```

Answer (score 1):

In one of my codes, I save the QActions into a separate List and generate the menus and submenus on demand. In theory, I can add "weight" to the items and have them re-ordered, but I have not implemented this yet.

Project page is available here: http://code.google.com/p/qtedit4/wiki/qmdilib

Please note that the actions of [QWidget](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qwidget.html) (and [QMenu](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qmenu.html)) are stored as a [QList](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qlist.html) which can be "read", using [QWidget::actions()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/qwidget.html#actions) . Remember that the list is copied, so you can modify the actions but not the list itself. (I hope I am not mistaking...)